# Android SlidingDrawer on top of the notification bar (or toggle visibility of that one)

Tags: android, android-widget, slidingdrawer

I am currently developing an application which is not fullscreen (Notification bar is visible). On the bottom of most of my activities, I have a sliding drawer that brings up a kind of dashboard. As of now, this sliding drawer is part of the main RelativeLayout and shows/hides fine. However, of course, it gets expanded up to the bottom of the notification area.

I would need this sliding drawer to cover the notification bar in order for it to take the whole screen. Maybe by attaching it to the main Layout instead of the activity Layout?

Another way that would be ok would be to hide the notification bar (maybe using an animation to slide it up) when the sliding drawer is opening and show it back when the drawer is closing.

Has anybody managed to do such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot draw Views on top of the notification bar. You can hide it by making your application fullscreen, but that's all.

Comment: And making the application fullscreen cannot be toggled at any time, am I right?

Comment: It can, but it's usually distracting.

Comment: Thanks, will try to make the UI usable without any workaround. Would be cool anyway if we could require the Notification Area to go away for some time.